# Bitbucket API: Using the API Issue and filter to get only requested data back

Tags: api, bitbucket-api

I am using the BB API and in particular the issues division. At the moment i am using the following to get all issue then looping through to get what i require but i noticed that we can add a filter option to get just the required issues back.

```
  $issue->all(account, repo);
```

But looking into the api code noticed the $options param. But i cannot find any doc or details on how to supply the $options values. I have tried the following

```
  $issue->all(account, repo, array('filter'=>array('status','new));
```

But this does not play ball.

So how can i use this third param $options so that i can use the filter setting?

for reference i am using [gentlero/bitbucket-api](https://bitbucket.org/gentlero/bitbucket-api/) for the php backend and this is where the all function is

Answer (score 0):

looking closer and with more paitence i used the following and it seemded to work:

```
  $issue->all(account, repo,array('status' => 'resolved'));
```

Comment: At first I wrote that library for some internal use and when I saw that no other PHP library existed for Bitbucket, I decided to open source it. I admit that has a poor documentation, but you can find a few "raw" usage example inside "[example](https://bitbucket.org/gentlero/bitbucket-api/src/415e5453835b8522b9f751089cf2f035e6b553a1/example?at=master)" directory from the repository. If you encounter any problems with this library or if you have suggestions, you can open an issue on Bitbucket. I hope the library will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The initial query request can be filtered if you append the following to the request

`?q=state="new"` or `?q=state="resolved"`

---

Examples:

Resolved issues:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/craigiswayne/pipelines-playground/issues?q=state=%22resolved%22

New issues:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/craigiswayne/pipelines-playground/issues?q=state=%22new%22

---

Documentation Reference:

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering#supp-endpoints